# How to set the location of a widget in GTK+?

Tags: gtk

Please, i need the function that can set the location of a Widget on gtk+ using pixels ! and an example of it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GtkFixed](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkFixed.html) container:

> The GtkFixed widget is a container which can place child widgets at fixed positions and with fixed sizes, given in pixels.

---

And since you didn't mention a language, here is an example in Python:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys

class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self, app):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="GtkFixed", application=app)
        # Set the window size
        self.set_size_request(200, 200)

        # Add GtkFixed to the main window
        container = Gtk.Fixed()
        self.add(container)

        button = Gtk.Button("Test Button")
        # Add the button in the (x=20,y=100) position
        container.put(button, 20, 100)


class Application(Gtk.Application):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        self.mainWindow = MainWindow(self)
        self.mainWindow.show_all()

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)


application = Application()

exitStatus = application.run(sys.argv)
sys.exit(exitStatus)
```

(unfortunately i can't post the result image)